# PHP submit and save to database

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have this submit form of PHP. Then when i submit it --it goes to my database.
It does save, but i need to refresh my page to see the data that has been save to my DB.

```
My Page -> Submit DB -> My Page
```

Sort of like that, so i in the save page when i do the submit function.

Why do i need to refresh my page to see the result of the data that has been saved?

Or do i need to create a new page? or do i need to add some queries on url?

Thank you.

UPDATED: 
Thank you for all the help guys.
I just used the isset, and its working now

Comment: You don't need to refresh the page at all, google AJAX. PS: Don't be surprized if this question gets down-voted, closed and deleted in a couple of minutes: The question is vague, doesn't describe a specific problem, there's no proof of any effort whatsoever, and it doesn't show any basic understanding of what you're asking about... check the help-center on what to ask

Comment: my boss client doesn't want to use jQuery and thats the hard part for me.

Comment: Put the save data before rendering the UI

Comment: or use [ob_start](http://be1.php.net/ob_start) to buffer output and `header('Location: '. $_PHP['SELF']);` to refresh the page after u stored the data in the DB

Comment: there's nothing, absolutely nothing, you can't do _without jQuery_ AJAX isn't a feature of jQuery, just learn some JS

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem I understand on your part.

Comment: @DarkBee: That won't work: form-submit => PHP -> DB => AJAX response with extra HTML of recently added data, and that's it. output buffering would still require a refresh

Comment: He is stating that ajax is just a mere httpxmlrequest

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : Thats why I added "and refresh the page with", the buffering is needed to avoid `headers are already sent` ;-)

Comment: @DarkBee: yes, but one of the OP's questions was: "Do I need to refresh the page". To which the answer is: No, with an AJAX request, you don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Submit DB` code is on same `My Page`. 
At the start of page check if submit button is clicked

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  //your insert query
}
?>
```

In your body tag

```
<?php
  // display your table
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably you're querying data first and then you're saving form to database. Check it and change sequence if it is true.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a single page both displaying, inserting and reading from/into database

```
<?php 

 if (isset($_POST['insert']) && $_POST['insert'] == "yes")
 {
   //run your insert query
 } 

 ?>
   <!-- put your form here -->
   remember to add the code below into your form
   <input type="hidden" name="insert" value="yes" />

   <!-- put your table here -->
```